# remove xml tags with XPath in c#

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I want to remove some tags from existing XML file using C#. My XML content is below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Invoice xmlns="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2" xmlns:cac="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2" xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2" xmlns:ext="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonExtensionComponents-2">
  <ext:UBLExtensions>
    <ext:UBLExtension>
      <ext:ExtensionURI>urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:dsig:enveloped:xades</ext:ExtensionURI>
      <ext:ExtensionContent>
        <sig:UBLDocumentSignatures xmlns:sig="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonSignatureComponents-2" xmlns:sac="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:SignatureAggregateComponents-2" xmlns:sbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:SignatureBasicComponents-2">
          <sac:SignatureInformation>
            <cbc:ID>urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:signature:1</cbc:ID>
            <sbc:ReferencedSignatureID>urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:signature:Invoice</sbc:ReferencedSignatureID>
            <ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" Id="signature">
              <ds:SignedInfo>
                <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2006/12/xml-c14n11" />
                <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#ecdsa-sha256" />
                <ds:Reference Id="invoiceSignedData" URI="">
                  <ds:Transforms>
                    <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116">
                      <ds:XPath>not(//ancestor-or-self::ext:UBLExtensions)</ds:XPath>
                    </ds:Transform>
                    <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116">
                      <ds:XPath>not(//ancestor-or-self::cac:Signature)</ds:XPath>
                    </ds:Transform>
                    <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116">
                      <ds:XPath>not(//ancestor-or-self::cac:AdditionalDocumentReference[cbc:ID='QR'])</ds:XPath>
                    </ds:Transform>
                    <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2006/12/xml-c14n11" />
                  </ds:Transforms>
                  <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256" />
                  <ds:DigestValue>PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiBlbmNvZGluZz0idXRmLTgiPz4NCjxJbnZva</ds:DigestValue>
                </ds:Reference>
                <ds:Reference Type="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#SignatureProperties" URI="#xadesSignedProperties">
                  <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256" />
                  <ds:DigestValue>Y2ZhM2ExNDEwYTNmODA1ZDc3MjVlMWMxYWUzMzIyZDFmZDIyZjhmMmU5YzM1MDgwMzE1YmIwODQ5ZTMzN2ZkOQ==</ds:DigestValue>
                </ds:Reference>
              </ds:SignedInfo>
              <ds:SignatureValue>MEUCIQChDLnZWprmUoLQLIEU5Z7LNlStc1MCCsgPgdrR6513ZgIgdxkNg/1Di92EcYIiamg9d6achtxfqQyxYn5mCdo4BgA=</ds:SignatureValue>
              <ds:KeyInfo>
                <ds:X509Data>
                  <ds:X509Certificate>MIID2zCCA4CgAwIBAgITbwAAdqDmIhqsjpm5CwABAAB2oDAKBggqhkjOPQQDA</ds:X509Certificate>
                </ds:X509Data>
              </ds:KeyInfo>
              <ds:Object>
                <xades:QualifyingProperties xmlns:xades="http://uri.etsi.org/01903/v1.3.2#" Target="signature">
                  <xades:SignedProperties Id="xadesSignedProperties">
                    <xades:SignedSignatureProperties>
                      <xades:SigningTime>2023-12-28T21:36:34Z</xades:SigningTime>
                      <xades:SigningCertificate>
                        <xades:Cert>
                          <xades:CertDigest>
                            <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256" />
                            <ds:DigestValue>YjcyNzI4NWZiN2FlNzI1NTQxOGIzZGY1ZWY4MDc2N2JkMDIyMDM5ZDU5YjJmNWRkOTQ5YTZkMDU2YjEzYzJkZA==</ds:DigestValue>
                          </xades:CertDigest>
                          <xades:IssuerSerial>
                            <ds:X509IssuerName>CN=TSZEINVOICE-SubCA-1, DC=extgazt, DC=gov, DC=local</ds:X509IssuerName>
                            <ds:X509SerialNumber>2475382886904809774818644480820936050208702411</ds:X509SerialNumber>
                          </xades:IssuerSerial>
                        </xades:Cert>
                      </xades:SigningCertificate>
                    </xades:SignedSignatureProperties>
                  </xades:SignedProperties>
                </xades:QualifyingProperties>
              </ds:Object>
            </ds:Signature>
          </sac:SignatureInformation>
        </sig:UBLDocumentSignatures>
      </ext:ExtensionContent>
    </ext:UBLExtension>
  </ext:UBLExtensions>
  <cbc:ProfileID>reporting:1.0</cbc:ProfileID>
  <cbc:ID>1-256559</cbc:ID>
  <cbc:UUID>f69ff49a-3f26-4561-8c46-b85097b1cf2a</cbc:UUID>
  <cbc:IssueDate>2023-07-28</cbc:IssueDate>
  <cbc:IssueTime>16:29:07</cbc:IssueTime>
  <cbc:InvoiceTypeCode name="0100000">388</cbc:InvoiceTypeCode>
  <cbc:DocumentCurrencyCode>SAR</cbc:DocumentCurrencyCode>
  <cbc:TaxCurrencyCode>SAR</cbc:TaxCurrencyCode>
  <cac:AdditionalDocumentReference>
    <cbc:ID>ICV</cbc:ID>
    <cbc:UUID>1</cbc:UUID>
  </cac:AdditionalDocumentReference>
  <cac:AdditionalDocumentReference>
    <cbc:ID>PIH</cbc:ID>
    <cac:Attachment>
      <cbc:EmbeddedDocumentBinaryObject mimeCode="text/plain">NWZlY2ViNjZmZmM4NmYzOGQ5NTI3ODZjNmQ2OTZjNzljMmRiYzIzOWRkNGU5MWI0NjcyOWQ3M2EyN2ZiNTdlOQ==</cbc:EmbeddedDocumentBinaryObject>
    </cac:Attachment>
  </cac:AdditionalDocumentReference>
  <cac:AdditionalDocumentReference>
    <cbc:ID>QR</cbc:ID>
    <cac:Attachment>
      <cbc:EmbeddedDocumentBinaryObject mimeCode="text/plain">
      </cbc:EmbeddedDocumentBinaryObject>
    </cac:Attachment>
  </cac:AdditionalDocumentReference>
  <cac:Signature>
    <cbc:ID>urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:signature:Invoice</cbc:ID>
    <cbc:SignatureMethod>urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:dsig:enveloped:xades</cbc:SignatureMethod>
  </cac:Signature>
  <cac:AccountingSupplierParty>
    <cac:Party>
      <cac:PartyIdentification>
        <cbc:ID schemeID="CRN">
        </cbc:ID>
      </cac:PartyIdentification>
      <cac:PostalAddress>
        <cbc:StreetName>
        </cbc:StreetName>
        <cbc:BuildingNumber>
        </cbc:BuildingNumber>
        <cbc:CitySubdivisionName>
        </cbc:CitySubdivisionName>
        <cbc:CityName>
        </cbc:CityName>
        <cbc:PostalZone>
        </cbc:PostalZone>
        <cac:Country>
          <cbc:IdentificationCode>SA</cbc:IdentificationCode>
        </cac:Country>
      </cac:PostalAddress>
      <cac:PartyTaxScheme>
        <cbc:CompanyID>311380797100003</cbc:CompanyID>
        <cac:TaxScheme>
          <cbc:ID>VAT</cbc:ID>
        </cac:TaxScheme>
      </cac:PartyTaxScheme>
      <cac:PartyLegalEntity>
        <cbc:RegistrationName>LAMARA SUPERMARKET</cbc:RegistrationName>
      </cac:PartyLegalEntity>
    </cac:Party>
  </cac:AccountingSupplierParty>
  <cac:AccountingCustomerParty>
    <cac:Party>
      <cac:PartyIdentification>
        <cbc:ID schemeID="NAT">
        </cbc:ID>
      </cac:PartyIdentification>
      <cac:PostalAddress>
        <cbc:StreetName>
        </cbc:StreetName>
        <cbc:BuildingNumber>
        </cbc:BuildingNumber>
        <cbc:CitySubdivisionName>
        </cbc:CitySubdivisionName>
        <cbc:CityName>
        </cbc:CityName>
        <cbc:PostalZone>
        </cbc:PostalZone>
        <cac:Country>
          <cbc:IdentificationCode>SA</cbc:IdentificationCode>
        </cac:Country>
      </cac:PostalAddress>
      <cac:PartyTaxScheme>
        <cbc:CompanyID>
        </cbc:CompanyID>
        <cac:TaxScheme>
          <cbc:ID>VAT</cbc:ID>
        </cac:TaxScheme>
      </cac:PartyTaxScheme>
      <cac:PartyLegalEntity>
        <cbc:RegistrationName>CASH ACCOUNT</cbc:RegistrationName>
      </cac:PartyLegalEntity>
    </cac:Party>
  </cac:AccountingCustomerParty>
  <cac:Delivery>
    <cbc:ActualDeliveryDate>2023-07-28</cbc:ActualDeliveryDate>
  </cac:Delivery>
  <cac:PaymentMeans>
    <cbc:PaymentMeansCode>10</cbc:PaymentMeansCode>
  </cac:PaymentMeans>
  <cac:AllowanceCharge>
    <cbc:ChargeIndicator>false</cbc:ChargeIndicator>
    <cbc:AllowanceChargeReason>discount</cbc:AllowanceChargeReason>
    <cbc:Amount currencyID="SAR">0.00</cbc:Amount>
    <cac:TaxCategory>
      <cbc:ID schemeID="UN/ECE 5305" schemeAgencyID="6">S</cbc:ID>
      <cbc:Percent>15</cbc:Percent>
      <cac:TaxScheme>
        <cbc:ID schemeID="UN/ECE 5153" schemeAgencyID="6">VAT</cbc:ID>
      </cac:TaxScheme>
    </cac:TaxCategory>
  </cac:AllowanceCharge>
  <cac:TaxTotal>
    <cbc:TaxAmount currencyID="SAR">4.56</cbc:TaxAmount>
  </cac:TaxTotal>
  <cac:TaxTotal>
    <cbc:TaxAmount currencyID="SAR">4.56</cbc:TaxAmount>
    <cac:TaxSubtotal>
      <cbc:TaxableAmount currencyID="SAR">30.39</cbc:TaxableAmount>
      <cbc:TaxAmount currencyID="SAR">4.56</cbc:TaxAmount>
      <cac:TaxCategory>
        <cbc:ID schemeID="UN/ECE 5305" schemeAgencyID="6">S</cbc:ID>
        <cbc:Percent>15.00</cbc:Percent>
        <cac:TaxScheme>
          <cbc:ID schemeID="UN/ECE 5153" schemeAgencyID="6">VAT</cbc:ID>
        </cac:TaxScheme>
      </cac:TaxCategory>
    </cac:TaxSubtotal>
  </cac:TaxTotal>
  <cac:LegalMonetaryTotal>
    <cbc:LineExtensionAmount currencyID="SAR">30.39</cbc:LineExtensionAmount>
    <cbc:TaxExclusiveAmount currencyID="SAR">30.39</cbc:TaxExclusiveAmount>
    <cbc:TaxInclusiveAmount currencyID="SAR">34.95</cbc:TaxInclusiveAmount>
    <cbc:AllowanceTotalAmount currencyID="SAR">0.00</cbc:AllowanceTotalAmount>
    <cbc:PrepaidAmount currencyID="SAR">0.00</cbc:PrepaidAmount>
    <cbc:PayableAmount currencyID="SAR">34.95</cbc:PayableAmount>
  </cac:LegalMonetaryTotal>
  <cac:InvoiceLine>
    <cbc:ID>1</cbc:ID>
    <cbc:InvoicedQuantity unitCode="PCE">1.00</cbc:InvoicedQuantity>
    <cbc:LineExtensionAmount currencyID="SAR">1.00</cbc:LineExtensionAmount>
    <cac:TaxTotal>
      <cbc:TaxAmount currencyID="SAR">0.15</cbc:TaxAmount>
      <cbc:RoundingAmount currencyID="SAR">1.15</cbc:RoundingAmount>
    </cac:TaxTotal>
    <cac:Item>
      <cbc:Name>
      </cbc:Name>
      <cac:ClassifiedTaxCategory>
        <cbc:ID>S</cbc:ID>
        <cbc:Percent>15</cbc:Percent>
        <cac:TaxScheme>
          <cbc:ID>VAT</cbc:ID>
        </cac:TaxScheme>
      </cac:ClassifiedTaxCategory>
    </cac:Item>
    <cac:Price>
      <cbc:PriceAmount currencyID="SAR">1.00</cbc:PriceAmount>
      <cac:AllowanceCharge>
        <cbc:ChargeIndicator>false</cbc:ChargeIndicator>
        <cbc:AllowanceChargeReason>discount</cbc:AllowanceChargeReason>
        <cbc:Amount currencyID="SAR">0.00</cbc:Amount>
      </cac:AllowanceCharge>
    </cac:Price>
  </cac:InvoiceLine>
  <cac:InvoiceLine>
    <cbc:ID>2</cbc:ID>
    <cbc:InvoicedQuantity unitCode="PCE">1.00</cbc:InvoicedQuantity>
    <cbc:LineExtensionAmount currencyID="SAR">2.00</cbc:LineExtensionAmount>
    <cac:TaxTotal>
      <cbc:TaxAmount currencyID="SAR">0.30</cbc:TaxAmount>
      <cbc:RoundingAmount currencyID="SAR">2.30</cbc:RoundingAmount>
    </cac:TaxTotal>
    <cac:Item>
      <cbc:Name>
      </cbc:Name>
      <cac:ClassifiedTaxCategory>
        <cbc:ID>S</cbc:ID>
        <cbc:Percent>15</cbc:Percent>
        <cac:TaxScheme>
          <cbc:ID>VAT</cbc:ID>
        </cac:TaxScheme>
      </cac:ClassifiedTaxCategory>
    </cac:Item>
    <cac:Price>
      <cbc:PriceAmount currencyID="SAR">2.00</cbc:PriceAmount>
      <cac:AllowanceCharge>
        <cbc:ChargeIndicator>false</cbc:ChargeIndicator>
        <cbc:AllowanceChargeReason>discount</cbc:AllowanceChargeReason>
        <cbc:Amount currencyID="SAR">0.00</cbc:Amount>
      </cac:AllowanceCharge>
    </cac:Price>
  </cac:InvoiceLine>
  <cac:InvoiceLine>
    <cbc:ID>3</cbc:ID>
    <cbc:InvoicedQuantity unitCode="PCE">1.00</cbc:InvoicedQuantity>
    <cbc:LineExtensionAmount currencyID="SAR">8.26</cbc:LineExtensionAmount>
    <cac:TaxTotal>
      <cbc:TaxAmount currencyID="SAR">1.24</cbc:TaxAmount>
      <cbc:RoundingAmount currencyID="SAR">9.50</cbc:RoundingAmount>
    </cac:TaxTotal>
    <cac:Item>
      <cbc:Name>
      </cbc:Name>
      <cac:ClassifiedTaxCategory>
        <cbc:ID>S</cbc:ID>
        <cbc:Percent>15</cbc:Percent>
        <cac:TaxScheme>
          <cbc:ID>VAT</cbc:ID>
        </cac:TaxScheme>
      </cac:ClassifiedTaxCategory>
    </cac:Item>
    <cac:Price>
      <cbc:PriceAmount currencyID="SAR">8.26</cbc:PriceAmount>
      <cac:AllowanceCharge>
        <cbc:ChargeIndicator>false</cbc:ChargeIndicator>
        <cbc:AllowanceChargeReason>discount</cbc:AllowanceChargeReason>
        <cbc:Amount currencyID="SAR">0.00</cbc:Amount>
      </cac:AllowanceCharge>
    </cac:Price>
  </cac:InvoiceLine>
  <cac:InvoiceLine>
    <cbc:ID>4</cbc:ID>
    <cbc:InvoicedQuantity unitCode="PCE">1.00</cbc:InvoicedQuantity>
    <cbc:LineExtensionAmount currencyID="SAR">5.22</cbc:LineExtensionAmount>
    <cac:TaxTotal>
      <cbc:TaxAmount currencyID="SAR">0.78</cbc:TaxAmount>
      <cbc:RoundingAmount currencyID="SAR">6.00</cbc:RoundingAmount>
    </cac:TaxTotal>
    <cac:Item>
      <cbc:Name>
      </cbc:Name>
      <cac:ClassifiedTaxCategory>
        <cbc:ID>S</cbc:ID>
        <cbc:Percent>15</cbc:Percent>
        <cac:TaxScheme>
          <cbc:ID>VAT</cbc:ID>
        </cac:TaxScheme>
      </cac:ClassifiedTaxCategory>
    </cac:Item>
    <cac:Price>
      <cbc:PriceAmount currencyID="SAR">5.22</cbc:PriceAmount>
      <cac:AllowanceCharge>
        <cbc:ChargeIndicator>false</cbc:ChargeIndicator>
        <cbc:AllowanceChargeReason>discount</cbc:AllowanceChargeReason>
        <cbc:Amount currencyID="SAR">0.00</cbc:Amount>
      </cac:AllowanceCharge>
    </cac:Price>
  </cac:InvoiceLine>
  <cac:InvoiceLine>
    <cbc:ID>5</cbc:ID>
    <cbc:InvoicedQuantity unitCode="PCE">1.00</cbc:InvoicedQuantity>
    <cbc:LineExtensionAmount currencyID="SAR">0.87</cbc:LineExtensionAmount>
    <cac:TaxTotal>
      <cbc:TaxAmount currencyID="SAR">0.13</cbc:TaxAmount>
      <cbc:RoundingAmount currencyID="SAR">1.00</cbc:RoundingAmount>
    </cac:TaxTotal>
    <cac:Item>
      <cbc:Name>ABCD</cbc:Name>
      <cac:ClassifiedTaxCategory>
        <cbc:ID>S</cbc:ID>
        <cbc:Percent>R15</cbc:Percent>
        <cac:TaxScheme>
          <cbc:ID>VAT</cbc:ID>
        </cac:TaxScheme>
      </cac:ClassifiedTaxCategory>
    </cac:Item>
    <cac:Price>
      <cbc:PriceAmount currencyID="SAR">0.87</cbc:PriceAmount>
      <cac:AllowanceCharge>
        <cbc:ChargeIndicator>false</cbc:ChargeIndicator>
        <cbc:AllowanceChargeReason>discount</cbc:AllowanceChargeReason>
        <cbc:Amount currencyID="SAR">0.00</cbc:Amount>
      </cac:AllowanceCharge>
    </cac:Price>
  </cac:InvoiceLine>
  <cac:InvoiceLine>
    <cbc:ID>6</cbc:ID>
    <cbc:InvoicedQuantity unitCode="PCE">2.00</cbc:InvoicedQuantity>
    <cbc:LineExtensionAmount currencyID="SAR">13.04</cbc:LineExtensionAmount>
    <cac:TaxTotal>
      <cbc:TaxAmount currencyID="SAR">1.96</cbc:TaxAmount>
      <cbc:RoundingAmount currencyID="SAR">15.00</cbc:RoundingAmount>
    </cac:TaxTotal>
    <cac:Item>
      <cbc:Name>
      </cbc:Name>
      <cac:ClassifiedTaxCategory>
        <cbc:ID>S</cbc:ID>
        <cbc:Percent>15</cbc:Percent>
        <cac:TaxScheme>
          <cbc:ID>VAT</cbc:ID>
        </cac:TaxScheme>
      </cac:ClassifiedTaxCategory>
    </cac:Item>
    <cac:Price>
      <cbc:PriceAmount currencyID="SAR">6.52</cbc:PriceAmount>
      <cac:AllowanceCharge>
        <cbc:ChargeIndicator>false</cbc:ChargeIndicator>
        <cbc:AllowanceChargeReason>discount</cbc:AllowanceChargeReason>
        <cbc:Amount currencyID="SAR">0.00</cbc:Amount>
      </cac:AllowanceCharge>
    </cac:Price>
  </cac:InvoiceLine>
</Invoice>
```

From above XML, I want to remove tags 'ext:UBLExtensions', 'cac:AdditionalDocumentReference' (with QR element), 'cac:Signature'.

I tried different methods discussed in other similar questions, but couldn't get a proper solution. I want to remove it with XPath only, otherwise hash value of the file gets changed.

One of the code I tried is below:

```
var xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(Server.MapPath("~/XML/311380797100003_20230728T162907_1-256559.xml"));
var element = (
    from x in xmlDoc.Root.Elements("Invoice")
    where x.Element("tage-name").Value == "ext:UBLExtensions"
    select x
    ).FirstOrDefault();
element.Remove();
xmlDoc.Save(Server.MapPath("~/XML/311380797100003_20230728T162907_1-256559.xml"));
```

But in this, this code is giving error, because I don't know how to use that.

Comment: It is better to use XSLT for such task.

Comment: XPath can select nodes in a document, but it cannot remove them. For that you need something else in addition to XPath; it could be C#/Linq code, XSLT code, XQuery code, etc.

Comment: I don't understand the comment "otherwise hash value of the file gets changed". If you change the contents of a file, it's hash value will change. That's the point of hash values.

Answer (score 0):

Try following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp10
{
    class Program
    {
        const string INPUT_FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        const string OUTPUT_FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test1.xml";
         static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(INPUT_FILENAME);

            XNamespace extNs = doc.Root.GetNamespaceOfPrefix("ext");
            XNamespace cacNs = doc.Root.GetNamespaceOfPrefix("cac");
            XNamespace cbcNs = doc.Root.GetNamespaceOfPrefix("cbc");

            XElement ublExt = doc.Descendants(extNs + "UBLExtensions").FirstOrDefault();
            ublExt.Remove();

            var qr = doc.Descendants(cacNs + "AdditionalDocumentReference").Where(x => (string)x.Element(cbcNs + "ID") == "QR");
            qr.Remove();

            XElement signature = doc.Descendants(cacNs + "Signature").FirstOrDefault();
            signature.Remove();


            doc.Save(OUTPUT_FILENAME);
        }
 
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with ***XPath only*** along with [`Remove()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.extensions.remove?view=net-8.0#system-xml-linq-extensions-remove-1(system-collections-generic-ienumerable((-0)))) as follows:

```cs
XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(new NameTable());
nsmgr.AddNamespace("ext", "urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonExtensionComponents-2");
nsmgr.AddNamespace("cac", "urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2");
nsmgr.AddNamespace("cbc", "urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2");

xmlDoc.XPathSelectElements(".//ext:UBLExtensions", nsmgr).Remove();
xmlDoc.XPathSelectElements(".//cac:Signature", nsmgr).Remove();
xmlDoc.XPathSelectElements(".//cac:AdditionalDocumentReference[./cbc:ID = 'QR']", nsmgr).Remove();
```

Notes:

- All of the elements in your XML are in namespaces, so when querying your XML you need to use an [`XmlNamespaceManager`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlnamespacemanager?view=net-8.0) as shown in *[Getting an XElement with a namespace via XPathSelectElements](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19866523)* to associate an actual namespace name with a prefix to be used in your query.  The prefix need not be the same as the prefix used in the XML.  Only the actual namespace name needs to match.
- Namespace **prefixes** such as `cbc:` are not semantically meaningful and should not be hardcoded as per [Namespaces in XML 1.0 (Third Edition): Qualified Names](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml-names/#NT-PrefixedName):

  > Note that the prefix functions only as a placeholder for a namespace name. Applications SHOULD use the namespace name, not the prefix, in constructing names whose scope extends beyond the containing document.

**Alternatively**, this can also be done with [LINQ to XML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/linq/linq-xml-overview) as follows:

```cs
XNamespace ext = "urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonExtensionComponents-2";
XNamespace cac = "urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2";
XNamespace cbc = "urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2";

string id = "QR";

xmlDoc.Descendants(ext + "UBLExtensions").Remove();
xmlDoc.Descendants(cac + "Signature").Remove();
xmlDoc.Descendants(cac + "AdditionalDocumentReference").Where(a =>  a.Element(cbc + "ID")?.Value == id).Remove();
```

Demo fiddle with both approaches [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/4KIFgB).