# How to read colon in xml file using c# linq

Tags: c#, xml

How can I read colon in xml file using c# linq

My code in c#

```cs
XDocument xdocc = XDocument.Load(files, LoadOptions.SetLineInfo);
var mml_hi_it = xdocc.Descendants("mml:hi").Where(s => (string)s.Attribute("rend").Value == "it");
```

Comment: Might you please [edit] your question to share a [mcve]?  To help you we will need to see a complete, well-formed XML sample (as text, not as an image) that demonstrates your problem.  See: [ask].  [using XElement to query for a node in namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4857172/3744182) may answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

The `mml` literal indicates the namespace used in your xml. You should be able to find the definition in the root node. For example, based on your comment, your root tag looks like following.

```
<article article-type="research-article" dtd-version="1.1" xml:lang="en" xmlns:mml="w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" xmlns:xlink="w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:oasis="niso.org/standards/z39-96/ns/oasis-exchange/table">
```

In order to access Element with namespace, you need to specify the namespace using [XNamespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xnamespace?view=netframework-4.8). For example,

```
XNamespace  mml = "w3.org/1998/Math/MathML";
var mml_hi_it = xdocc.Descendants(mml + "hi").Where(s => (string)s.Attribute("rend").Value == "it");
```

Comment: I have updated the answer. Please verify. If it doesn't work, could you please share your xml. You could update the OP to include the xml

Comment: <article article-type="research-article" dtd-version="1.1" xml:lang="en" xmlns:mml="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:oasis="http://www.niso.org/standards/z39-96/ns/oasis-exchange/table">

Comment: this is my xml:

Comment: @MicwillAragon What exactly do you want to fetch from this ?

Comment: @MicwillAragon That xml seems to contain only the namespaces. Is that the complete xml (atleast one required for the question ) ? It would be great if you could edit the Question and add the Xml (with all required parts)

Comment: <article article-type="research-article" dtd-version="1.1" xml:lang="en" xmlns:mml="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:oasis="http://www.niso.org/standards/z39-96/ns/oasis-exchange/table" xmlns="http://www.adventure-works.com" xmlns:mml="www.somenamespace.com"> i put your code root here in article tag

Comment: @MicwillAragon That was an example since your xml was missing. I have updated the answer based on your xml you have shared. Please check the updated answer now. You do not need to alter your original xml for the answer.